# How to resize a custom view programmatically?

Tags: android, resize

I am coding a custom view, extended from RelativeLayout, and I want to resize it programmatically, How can I do?

the custom view Class is something like:

```
public ActiveSlideView(Context context, AttributeSet attr){
        super(context, attr);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(inflater != null){       
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.active_slide, this);
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set ImageView Size Programmatically in DP Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803313/set-imageview-size-programmatically-in-dp-java)

Answer (score 137, accepted):

```
this.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, theSizeIWant));
```

Problem solved!

NOTE: Be sure to use the parent Layout's `LayoutParams`. Mine is `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`!

Comment: Wut. Why wouldn't you use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams?`

Comment: This didn't work for me , i got a class cast exception for it .

Comment: @Tapan Thanker Use the Parent layout's LayoutParams. And My Parent layout is LinearLayout.

Comment: I wrote a more generic version of this: `private void resizeView(View view, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
  try {
   Constructor<? extends LayoutParams> ctor = view.getLayoutParams().getClass().getDeclaredConstructor(int.class, int.class);
   view.setLayoutParams(ctor.newInstance(newWidth, newHeight));
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }`

Comment: Why not change the params of the existing layout? `someLayout.getLayoutParams()`

Comment: You don't need to use the parent Layout's viewgroup, just do it like this: ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();

Comment: @atroutt You should put that as an answer.  I used that method and it worked perfectly.  I'l upvote it!

Comment: As requested, posted separate answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38250295/338642 @Grux

Comment: Since this answer is almost 4 years old FILL_PARENT should be replaced with MATCH_PARENT

Comment: This will reset all the other parameters to default values. @smisiewicz answer is better.

Answer (score 276):

Android throws an exception if you fail to pass the height or width of a view.
Instead of creating a new LayoutParams object, use the original one, so that all other set parameters are kept. Note that the type of LayoutParams returned by getLayoutParams is that of the *parent* layout, not the view you are resizing.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) someLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 130;
someLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: As @HerbertD mentions I also get an error doing this unless I use LinearLayout.LayoutParams, even through it is a RelativeLayout that I am resizing.

Comment: @Eigo According to the Android documentation, the LayoutParams are passed to the parent View, as this is the view which is responsible for the layout.

Comment: Whether the in value should be converted into dp value or it would work.

Comment: This is also preferable as it avoids instantiating a new LayoutParams object unnecessarily

Answer (score 74):

This works for me:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
params.height = customHeight;
layout.requestLayout();
```

Comment: This is much better than the other answers because this code doesn't require to know the exact type of the parent ViewGroup.

Comment: Do you know what's the difference between calling requestLayout() and calling setLayoutParams(params) ?

Comment: setLayoutParams(params) includes requestLayout().

Answer (score 52):

In Kotlin, you can use the [ktx extensions](https://android.github.io/android-ktx/core-ktx/androidx.view/index.html):

```
yourView.updateLayoutParams {
   height = <YOUR_HEIGHT>
}
```

Answer (score 50):

For what it's worth, let's say you wanted to resize the view in **device independent pixels** (**dp**): -

You need to use a method called `applyDimension`, that's a member of the class `TypedValue` to convert from dp to pixels. So if I want to set the height to 150dp (say) - then I could do this:

```
float pixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 150, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) someLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.height = (int) pixels;
someLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

where the expression: `getResources().getDisplayMetrics()` gets the screen density/resolution

Comment: Instead of hard coding your dimension you can also use this for the height in pixel:
`float pixels = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.card_height);`

Answer (score 7):

Here's a more generic version of the solution above from @herbertD :

```
private void resizeView(View view, int newWidth, int newHeight) { 
    try { 
        Constructor<? extends LayoutParams> ctor = view.getLayoutParams().getClass().getDeclaredConstructor(int.class, int.class); 
        view.setLayoutParams(ctor.newInstance(newWidth, newHeight));   
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

try a this one:

```
...
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.active_slide, this);
view.setMinimumWidth(200);
```

Answer (score 5):

I used this way to increase width of custom view

```
customDrawingView.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                View view_instance = customDrawingView;
                                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view_instance
                                        .getLayoutParams();
                                int newLayoutWidth = customDrawingView
                                        .getWidth()
                                        + customDrawingView.getWidth();
                                params.width = newLayoutWidth;
                                view_instance.setLayoutParams(params);
                                screenWidthBackup = params.width;
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 5):

With Kotlin and using dp unit:

```
myView.updateLayoutParams {
    val pixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 200f, context.resources.displayMetrics)
    height = pixels.toInt()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved it this way.. I have basically a simple view inside xml file.

```
 View viewname = findViewById(R.id.prod_extra);
             prodExtra.getLayoutParams().height=64;
```

Comment: haha, very naive but well working way, however I recommend to call setLayoutParams() eventually to properly propagate change to possible nested children, so after updating .width and .height, call view.setLayoutParams(view.getLayoutParams()) this is also always type proof

Comment: @Bhargav Rao could you help me on this topic:  `https://stackoverflow.com/q/44259342/6596724`

Answer (score 3):

If you have only `two or three condition(sizes)` then you can use **@Overide** `onMeasure` like

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) 
{
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

> And change your size for these conditions in CustomView class easily.

Answer (score 3):

This is how it can be done in Kotlin:

updateLayoutParams:

```
val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, binding.ssss, false).apply {
            id = View.generateViewId()

            updateLayoutParams { 
                height = 200
                width = 400 
            }

        }
binding.ssss.addView(view)
```

OR

layoutParams:

```
val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, binding.ssss, false).apply {
            id = View.generateViewId()
            
            layoutParams.width = 200
            layoutParams.height = 200
            
        }
binding.ssss.addView(view)
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are overriding `onMeasure`, don't forget to update the new sizes

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(newWidth, newHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I achieved this. In [Sileria](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15661239/8199772) answer he/she did the following:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
params.height = customHeight;
layout.requestLayout();
```

This is correct, but it expects us to give the height in `pixels`, but I wanted to give the `dp` I want the height to be so I added:

```
public int convertDpToPixelInt(float dp, Context context) {
    return (int) (dp * (((float) context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) / 160.0f));
}
```

So it will look like this:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
params.height = convertDpToPixelInt(50, getContext());
layout.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did:

```
View myView;  
myView.getLayoutParams().height = 32;  
myView.getLayoutParams().width = 32;
```

If there is a view group that this view belongs to, you may also need to call yourViewGroup.requestLayout() for it to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun View.setSize(width: Int, height: Int) {
    updateLayoutParams {
        this.width = width
        this.height = height
    }
}
```