# Best way to change width/height of a widget programmatically?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: How to resize a custom view programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963152/android-how-to-resize-a-custom-view-programmatically)

What's the best way to change width/height of a widget (I mean, a UI widget, subclass of android.view.View) programmatically?

Doing something like this works, but it doesn't seem quite right:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mSomeView.getLayoutParams();
params.height += 10;
mSomeView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Do you mean "widget" (i.e., subclass of `android.view.View`) or "app widget" (i.e., thingamajig that goes on the home screen)?

Comment: This code works fine, You don't need third line `mSomeView.setLayoutParams(params);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been using this approach when to change LayoutParams attributes and it seems good enough for me. After googling i haven't found any other good way to do this.