# Can I scale a View in Android?

Tags: android, view, scale

Can I take a view that has been rendered by the Android framework and rescale it to some other size?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963152/android-how-to-resize-a-custom-view-programmatically

Comment: I am not just trying to set the size of a view-- I would like to take a view and scale it down to a smaller size, basically taking a thumbnail of the view after it has been laid out.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You need API 11 or above to scale a view. Here is how:

```
float scalingFactor = 0.5f; // scale down to half the size
view.setScaleX(scalingFactor);
view.setScaleY(scalingFactor);
```

Comment: Praise be to God. This tiny piece of code worked amazingly well for me !! :) Thank you !

Comment: In this case it's scaled but still taking the original area in the layout !! any solutions?

Comment: @HamzehSoboh, I have same issue, Have find any solution?

Comment: @Pranav use layout params to scale, it'll adapt the view itself and give a rel dimensions.

Answer (score 10):

In your XML

```
android:scaleX="0.5"
android:scaleY="0.5"
```

Answer (score 4):

For scale, I **resize** the `width` and `height` of the view to make it affect the **area** and **position** `another view`.
If you **don't** want it affect the area and position, use answer of `@Gadzair` and `@Taiti`

```
private void resize(View view, float scaleX, float scaleY) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.width = (int) (view.getWidth() * scaleX);
    layoutParams.height = (int) (view.getHeight() * scaleY);
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Example using

```
resize(view, 0.5f, 0.8f);
```

Result
[image: Example]

[Demo](https://github.com/PhanVanLinh/AndroidScaleView)

Comment: Is it possible to do this with animation?

Comment: be careful to use this solution. because width & height is int, scale is float -> if you care about ratio of width and height, this way can lead to wrong ratio.