# Android how to replace the view after sometime?

Tags: android, layout, view, replace

In my layout i have two views at bottom like this

[image]

color view and buttons view i want replace the button view after 5 seconds with color view ( button view hide) , if user press button i want display the button view at the same place , color view moves to top of button view .
 how can i achieve this. please help me..

Comment: Use the timer and TimerTask class. TimerTask will contain the code to execute every 5 seconds. And the timer can be used to schedule the task.

Comment: using timer how can i replace the view

Comment: put whatever code you have done so far. That will help to pin point whats worng.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {          
  public void run() {
      ButtonView.setVisibility(View.GONE);      
      }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: after button view hide color view goes to top of the view , here i am using relative layouts.

Comment: RelativeLayout might be a problem here. add both the layouts in a vertical linearlayout. the code will work just fine.
Also add a bit of code that you've tried so far. that might help us find the problem

Comment: see the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963152/android-how-to-resize-a-custom-view-programmatically) and u'll find how to resize the view programmatically.