# Dynamically change width of spinner in Android

Tags: android, dynamic, width, spinner, layoutparams

I tried to dynamically change the width of a spinner with the code below, but I get an error message. What is the correct way to do this?

```
Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.s1_10);
s1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(400, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to resize a custom view programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963152/android-how-to-resize-a-custom-view-programmatically)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do something like the following, i know it looks ugly, but this seems like the only way at the moment.

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mSomeView.getLayoutParams();
params.width += 10;
s1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Yes, ended up using RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) s1.getLayoutParams();
  lp.width = 400;
  s1.setLayoutParams(lp);