# Make a layout in xml that can be changed programatically adding items

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to make a layout in xml for a Fragment class. This layout have to be match_parent width and height.

Picture 1

[image]

In picture 1, the layout has four items added programatically...

Picture 2

[image]

In picture 2 is the same layout but with 6 items.

none of these layouts examples are scrollable, so if i add 8 items, all items has to fit to
the screen size.

how can i do this?

Comment: I think this can help u: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963152/android-how-to-resize-a-custom-view-programmatically

Comment: close but not same, if i use TableView?

Comment: can you put an example? i googled examples but all are scrollable i need no scrollable

Comment: Refer this http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/, http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You can uses ScrollView.
if you use GridView now, ScrollView is contain GridView.
Or
You use over scroll mode if ifContentScrolls mode.

Comment: what about tableview?

Comment: you mean TableLayout? Almost layout's parent is ViewGroup. So you should it. I try this, it is success.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `layout_weight` attribute in `LinearLayout` as below...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="Menu 1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="Menu 2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="Menu 1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="Menu 2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="Menu 3" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="Menu 4" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="Menu 5" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="Menu 6" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="Menu 7" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="Menu 8" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply: refer to the LinearLayout by id, and add children programatically. If you want its children to have the same height, set their height to 0px and their weight to the same, 1 for instance. Since its children will be Linearlayouts as well, you can add the items manu1, menu2, etc to them without problem. I don't know you exact usage, but it's a start.