# Adding button after listview in custom dialog

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-dialog

I'm trying to add a button after `ListView` in a custom `Dialog` using `addFooterView()` method. `birthday_friend_contact_dialog.xml` code..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/friend_contact_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
```

`birthday_footerview_button.xml`..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/birthday_friend_footer_button"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel_contact_dialog"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Cancel" />
```

adding `Button` in custom `Dialog` below `ListView` using the following code..

```
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(AddNewFriend.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.birthday_friend_contact_dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("Select Contact...");

            ListView contactList = (ListView) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.friend_contact_list);

            //////Some code for listview adapter

            View footerLayout = (View)dialog.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.birthday_footerview_button,null);
            Button dialogButton = (Button) footerLayout
                    .findViewById(R.id.cancel_contact_dialog);
            contactList.addFooterView(footerLayout);

            dialog.show();
```

But `Button` doesn't appear below `ListView`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with list view height, mostly, listviews have issues with wrap content. Try to set fix height or set it's height to match parent.

Comment: how can i set `ListView` height as a percentage of total screen height?

Comment: Set android:layout_height="match_parent" if you want to set it's height same as its parent. But if you want to it's height as percentage of the screen height, Then you can programatically sets its height(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963152/android-how-to-resize-a-custom-view-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got a solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText android:id="@+id/friend_search"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:hint="Search contact.."
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel_contact_dialog"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="Cancel" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/friend_contact_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/friend_search"
    android:layout_above="@id/cancel_contact_dialog"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
```