# How can I add Views dynamically in a Relative layout or in any Layout

Tags: java, android, viewgroup

Well, my problem is little bit complicated(for me).
Suppose i have a `RelativeLayout`(Or any other `Layout` as needed).

Now i make some `View` like `TextView`.(multiple `View`).
Those `View` will include following characteristics i will give from java code.

1. I want to add the `View` to the Layout in a specific position.
2. Two or more `View` can be overlapped (like following picture)
3. It is kind of AddView(child, positionX, width, height); i know there is no method like this. but i need one.

where positionX is will be an integer defining where the `View` will be set in the `Layout` from top.

Now i want to add those `View` to the `Layout` like the following photo.

[image]

(All `View` will be of rectangular size; Sorry for the bad Editing.)

How can i do this?
I badly need the solution.

I hope i have explained my problem with my poor English :(

Thank you in advance <3 <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//-----Main Layout-----\\
LinearLayout l1 = findViewById(R.id.myLinear);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

//-----First layout-----\\
LinearLayout l11 = new LinearLayout(this);
l11.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark);
l1.addView(l11, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

//-----Second layout-----\\
LinearLayout l12 = new LinearLayout(this);
l12.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.holo_green_dark);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(-30, 20, 20, 0); //Negative margin top to superposition views
l1.addView(l12, layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 2):

As you've mentioned,

> All View will be of rectangular size

So let's take a button `yourButton` for example. You need to pass two values, one from top & one from left where you want to put the view. Then use the following method, as you wanted it `addView()` to achieve the desired output in a `RelativeLayout`:

```
private void addView(child, positionFromTop, positionFromLeft, width, height) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.topMargin = (int)(positionFromTop);
    layoutParams.leftMargin = (int)(positionFromLeft);
    yourButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

You can customize the layout using the width and height in the similar way programmatically, if required. Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4961199/11040422) to get the code of how to resize a custom view programmatically. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [FlexBox layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) provided by google to add view dynamically. You can check this [Medium](https://medium.com/gett-engineering/android-div-like-flexbox-layout-55f0e1286d66) post for clear concept about Flexbox Layout

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add multiple views dynamically maybe try to refactor them into one compund view (it will be easier to position them)

https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html

What type of ViewGroup do you use? If its constraint layout you can set constraints programatically using ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams in same way as SaadAAkash mentioned